# Missing time in Tomcat during startup. Startup speed

Tags: java, tomcat

My tomcat application has 20 .jar under lib folder. It takes about 8 seconds to startup.
I am wounding is it any method to make it faster to start?

So I set my tomcat's logging level to see what is happening.
I found that there are 4 seconds between WebappLoader STARTED log and StandardWrapper INITIALIZING.

Does anyone know what is happening in between? Is it no way to make it faster for that 20 .jar to loaded?

Below is the logging:

> 01-Jul-2021 22:45:04.390 FINE [localhost-startStop-1]
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state
> for [WebappLoader[/test]] to [STARTED]

> 01-Jul-2021 22:45:08.220 FINE [localhost-startStop-1]
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state
> for
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test].StandardWrapper[default]]
> to [INITIALIZING]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete guide on Tomcat startup optimization is available on [Apache's wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp).

In the 4 seconds between the log records Tomcat:

1. Loads the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` and scans the application jars for `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` entries. This is pretty fast, but you can refine it configuring a [`JarScanFilter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/jar-scan-filter.html) or using the system properties:

```
# Default value of `pluggabilitySkip`
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip
# Default value of `pluggabilityScan`
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan
```

2. Looks for [`ServletContainerInitializer`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletcontainerinitializer)s. This should also be fast, but it will influence the next step. You can limit the list of SCIs found with an `<absolute-ordering>` element in your `web.xml`.

   The SCIs used by the Websocket API and JSP API can not be disabled this way, you need to use the [`containerSciFilter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute of the `<Context>` element:

```xml
<!-- Disables both SCIs -->
<Context containerSciFilter="WsSci|JasperInitializer" />
```

3. The heaviest part is the scanning of class files in your application. The folder `WEB-INF/classes` and all jars with a `web-fragment.xml` found in step 1 will be scanned. To disable the scan you need to add the attribute `metadata-complete="true"` to your `web.xml` descriptor **and** disable all SCIs (or just leave those like Jasper, which don't scan for annotations).

Most of the magic happens in the [`ContextConfig#webConfig`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/5dcc5aa726f6b39b2a74d4d914375b65c9c9fc5d/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/ContextConfig.java#L1238) method, which is nicely commented.